# Make size of ListPolarPlot with PolarAxes consistent

Tags: plotting, style

I am currently having an issue with [`ListPolarPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPolarPlot.html), specifically with achieving a consistent size among multiple plots. Consider the following illustration of my issues:

```
(* some common options for the plots *)
opts = {PolarAxes -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled@0.12, ImageSize -> 350};

tests[pr_] := {
  ListPolarPlot[Table[{i, (Cos@i)^2}, {i, 0, 2 π, π/10}], PlotRange -> pr, opts],
  ListPolarPlot[Table[{i, 1.26 (Cos@i)^2}, {i, 0, 2 π, π/10}], PlotRange -> pr, opts],
  ListPolarPlot[Table[{i, (Cos@i)^10}, {i, 0, 2 π, π/500}], PlotRange -> pr, opts]
  }

tests /@ {All, Automatic, Full}
```

[image]

Note how neither of the option values produces consistent results: `All` is broken for the middle plot, `Automatic` for the last one, and let's not even talk about `Full`...

Is there any way to get sizing consistent, without resorting to manual adjustments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following fixes the problem by changing the definition of `ListPolarPlot`:

```
Begin["Graphics`PolarPlotDump`"];
If[!TrueQ@$FixedPolarPlots,
 DownValues[listPolarPlot] = DownValues[listPolarPlot] /.
   expr : HoldPattern[allPos = _] :> 
     (expr; maxRadius = Max[maxRadius, layoutData@"RadialAxesRadius"]);
 $FixedPolarPlots = False;
 ]
End[];

tests@All
```

[image]

## What does this do

To understand why this works, we first notice that `PlotRange->All` is pretty close to what we need, it just has issues for the middle plot. Looking at the `PlotRange` specified for the resulting three plots gives the following:

```
Options[#, PlotRange] & /@ tests[All]
(* {
     {PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}},
     {PlotRange -> {{-1.26, 1.26}, {-1.26, 1.26}}},
     {PlotRange -> {{-1., 1.}, {-1., 1.}}}
   } *)
```

Note how the `PlotRange` in the middle plot is based only on the data (with a max value of `1.26`), whereas the radial axis of the plot goes up to `1.5`, presumably because it's a nicer number. The fix is now easy: We simply need to adjust the `PlotRange` by the range of the radial axis if necessary, to ensure that the plot always shows at least the polar axes.

And this is exactly what the code above does: It inserts a single line into the code that adjusts `maxRadius` (used to compute absolute values `PlotRange->All`) to be at least as big as `layoutData@"RadialAxesRadius"`, which is set to the range of the radial axis (or `0` if none is drawn).